# what connection is taken at runtime in SSIS

Tags: ssis

1)
I have a SSIS package and am using package parameter to configure the connections to point to dev. db . Now if i use the environment variables to pass a different connection value pointing to test,  after i deploy to the SSIS catalog and further schedule it using the SQL Agent Job.
What connection info. will be taken at runtime , when the job is scheduled to run. Will it be dev or a test conn??
2)
I have a SSIS package and am using project parameter to configure the connections to point to dev. db . Now if i use the environment variables to pass a different connection value pointing to test,  after i deploy to the SSIS catalog and further schedule it using the SQL Agent Job.
What connection info. will be taken at runtime , when the job is scheduled to run. Will it be dev or a test conn??

Comment: What's the difference between these 2 questions?

Answer (score 0):

Answer on the first question depends on whether you are using SSIS Package Configurations or not. Possibly not, since you are talking about environment variables, but if you still do and use it together with Environment Variables - see [Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682.aspx) on that, and note this behavior changes with SSIS 2008 version.
If you are using SSIS Catalog and Package/Project variables, then mind this simple rule - more specific wins. In your case, the following precedence will take place, going to the next value if former is missing:

1. Value specified at package start, either with execution or dtexec parameters.
2. Value mapped with Environment Variable.
3. Vales specified at Package design time.

Here is another [Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213214.aspx) on package parameter value mapping.